# Karma unit testing - error during loading plugin

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I'm trying to run my first unit tests using karma with karma-junit-reporter plugin. Currently I'm getting this warning:

```
> node node_modules/karma/bin/karma start test/karma.conf.js

WARN [plugin]: Error during loading "karma-junit-reporter" plugin:
  Cannot find module 'xmlbuilder'
WARN [reporter]: Can not load "junit", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
```

But I installed that plugin in my app's main folder (using npmbox since I don't have access to the internet) and xmlbuilder folder is placed in node_modules.
Here's part of my karma config:

```
frameworks: ['jasmine-jquery','jasmine'],

    browsers : ['Chrome'],

        plugins : [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-junit-reporter',
            'karma-jasmine-jquery',
            'karma-jasmine'
            ],

    reporters: ['junit'],

    junitReporter : {
      outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
      suite: 'unit'
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure the directory ./node_modules/xmlbuilder is exist.

when you run npm install somemodule at D:/test, it will be stored to D:/test/node_modules/somemodule, then you can require this module in D:/test/*.js, and you can not require it at D:/other/place/*.js. If you hope the module can be required anywhere you should run :

```
npm install somemodule -g
```